# How can I determine which page is active/we are on in php

Tags: php, html, css

My problem is simple, and I've been trying to think of a way around this for a while. Essentially, I have a free HTML template which I downloaded. The entire template is in html only, meaning if I change something in the header, I have to go through 10 pages and change the HTML code for the header. So my solution was to remove the header html code and put a have another file called `header.php` and just echo it on all the pages.

**However**, there is a problem. As you can see, on the first line it says `<li class="nav-item active">`. There is an `active` bit. So whatever page we are currently on, we have to put active next to `nav-item`. Then to further complicate this... If you have a drop down menu, the `class=` looks difference. If you are on a page which is on a dropdown menu Like this `<li class="nav-item submenu dropdown active">`

So my question is, how can I detect what page I am on and make sure to put the `active` bit in the right section?

---

When we are on `index.html`

```
<li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="about-us.html">About</a></li>
<li class="nav-item submenu dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="portfolio-det.html">Portrfolio Dets</a>
    </ul>
</li>
```

When we are on `portfolio-det.html`, a sub-section of Portfolio. (Look at line 3, you'll see `active`)

```
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="about-us.html">About</a></li>
<li class="nav-item submenu dropdown active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="portfolio-det.html">Portrfolio Dets</a>
    </ul>
</li>
```

As you can see

Comment: Take a look at [`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: @Nick if I use this in my `header.php` to calculate where to put the active bit, it will just return the directory of `header.php`?

Comment: @Yuri if you're including `header.php` in each file, you will get the URL of the file, not `header.php`

Comment: @digijay Not a duplicate. I don't want to get the url in` header.php`. I want to get the directory of header.php. I want it for the page saying <?php echo header.php ?>

Comment: @Yuri it should be `<?php include 'header.php' ?>` or `<?php require 'header.php' ?>`

Comment: How do you "echo" content of header.php ? With include/require?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this it might help you.

So first you need to get the URL and than match the url with a proper ID to make the menu that you active to be active

```
<?php 

$get_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];


?>


 <script>
    $("#" + '<?php echo $get_url ?>').addClass('active');
 </script>
```

But since you have .html in your url we will want to strip it

```
$get_url = str_replace(".html", "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

So once we have that you need to add id's to your HTML

```
<li id="about-us" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="about-us.html">About</a></li>
```

If you are on the page "portfolio.html" it should light up

Hope this helps or that I at least understood your question correctly

Comment: Its not an ID though. The active is in the class. So how do I determine where to put the `active` string

Comment: @Yuri thats the idea, you target the ID and you name the ID as your URL and when they match the jQuery will add the class active

Comment: Oh I see. So the id should be the same as the url. Though what if the url is in folders like `test/another-test/about.html`

Comment: @Yuri well you're gonna have to make some if statements with php

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering using JavaScript, try to detect *current link* using `location.pathname`, then go through all the parents and add the `active` class for nodes that have the `nav-item` class.

The following solution should do the job.

```
var url = location.pathname.substr(1), // remove trailing slash
link = document.querySelector('.nav-link[href$="' + url + '"]');

if (link) {
    var item = link.parentNode;
    while (item.className && (item.nodeName === 'UL' || item.nodeName === 'LI')) {
        if (item.className.indexOf('nav-item') > -1) {
            item.className += ' active';
        }
        item = item.parentNode;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added below the code how you could use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], this method should work perfectly. The if condition checks if the name index is inside your url.I hope I could help you (It is not an optimal solution but it shows you how you could use it for your specific problem).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
     </head>
     <body>
        <h1>Index PHP</h1>
        <?php
           include 'menu.php';
        ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This is the Second.php page.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
     </head>
     <body>
        <h1>Second PHP</h1>
        <?php
         include 'menu.php';
         echo "Second page!";
        ?>
     </body>
  </html>
```

This is the menu.php which you wanted to include.

```
<?php 
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];


if (strpos($url,'index') !== false) {
    echo '<li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="index.php">First page</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item "><a class="nav-link" href="second.php">Second Page</a></li> ';
} else {
    echo ' <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="index.php">First page</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="second.php">Second Page</a></li>';
}

?> 

<style>
    .active{
        background-color: green;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined very important part in your question - how do you "echo" your header.php file?

> OP: The entire template is in **html** only

I ask you this, because usually you cannot just add PHP code in your .html file and expect it to run.

I assume you use standard include/require functions, and that you still run html templates on your server, correct?

Assuming that, you simply have to define an active page variable in your *.html files, for each file a different value of course, and then check in your header.php what the requested page is. You can use that variable's value to adjust other content in the header, as well.

I assume this directory structure:

```
root
|_ index.html
|_ about-us.html
|_ portfolio.html
|_ portfolio-det.html
|_ header.php
```

**STEP 1:** rename all your .html files to .php file extension:

I assume this directory structure:

```
root
|_ index.php
|_ about-us.php
|_ portfolio.php
|_ portfolio-det.php
|_ header.php
```

**STEP 2:** replace all the internal references in navigation links from .html to .php (be careful, triple-check everything!)

**STEP 3:** define $page variable that will hold a keyword which template you are on. Example code (tested) is below:

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>INDEX</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $page = 'home';
        require_once('header.php');
        ?>
        <div>INDEX</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**portfolio.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PORTFOLIO</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $page = 'portfolio';
        require_once('header.php');
        ?>
        <div>PORTFOLIO</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**portfolio-det.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PORTFOLIO-DET</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $page = 'portfolio';
        require_once('header.php');
        ?>
        <div>PORTFOLIO-DET</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**header.php**

```
<li class="nav-item <?php if($page == 'home') { echo 'active'; } ?>"><a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li class="nav-item <?php if($page == 'about-us') { echo 'active'; } ?>"><a class="nav-link" href="about-us.php">About</a></li>
<li class="nav-item submenu dropdown <?php if($page == 'portfolio') { echo 'active'; } ?>">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="portfolio.php">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="portfolio-det.php">Portrfolio Dets</a>
    </ul>
</li>
```